# Force phone number format as it's being entered

Tags: angularjs

I've inheritied a project, and the client has asked for a reasonable change. Currently, whenever the user enters the phone number, we have:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="phone.phoneNumber" ui-mask="999-999-9999" style="width:118px;" />
```

So that the number appears to be in the `123-456-7890` format. However, when viewed later, it shows as `1234567890`. I've tried:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="phone.phoneNumber" required ng-pattern="\(?(\d{3})\)?-?(\d{3})-(\d{4})" style="width:118px;" />
```

But this seems to cause it to stop binding. I'm new to learning AngularJS and I'm not even sure how to force this. What would be the best way to ensure that the data that is bound to the model is in the proper format?

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like ui-mask doesn't update the model with the formatted phone number, I'm sure this is by design.  I think you could continue to use ui-mask on all your inputs to show the phone number and leave the model value unformatted.

Another option is to use some combination of ngModelController formatters/parsers and roll your own solution (including implementing your own validation).  Since the ui-mask directive puts a parser function onto ngModelController, you may run into conflicts with it if you try to use both ui-mask and your own parser function.

I made a small example with an input marked with ui-mask and an input marked with a custom directive which formats the model value when it is read (and will modify the model to match the formatted value after the first change to the input).

This example is **not** comprehensive, but more of a way to help you decide your best course of action depending on your needs.

http://plnkr.co/edit/fbZ5rLOKNwmDcmycc4UF

You may want to read up more on ngModelController here:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController